# git: как сделать локальную копию только части репозитория?

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий git лежащий на сервере. Он содержит все файлы, необходимые для сборки программы на разных платформах, включая сторонние библиотеки. Я разрабатываю под Windows, мне не нужны файлы необходимые для сборки программы под Linux. И эти файлы для Linux занимают несколько гигабайт.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможноть в своей локальной копии репозитория держать только те файлы, которые мне реально нужны и не держать файлы, которые не нужны и занимают много места?

Comment: Никак. Гит оперирует цельными репозоториями

Comment: В индексе будет всё, но если цель не видеть в рабочем каталоге, то создайте локальный commit, который удалит это всё.  Или используйте хуки, тогда во время воссоздания каталога будет происходить убиение части файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл обходное решение. Я удалил все ненужные файлы, а затем выполнил для них команду

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged имя/файла
```

В результате они стали не видны в списке изменённых файлов.

Comment: Не уверен, что с этим получится нормально работать

Comment: А можно больше подробностей: почему не получится? Какие сложности могут при этом возникнуть. Пока неделю работают с таким репозиторием - каких то проблем или не удобств не обнаружил.

Comment: Попробуйте переключиться на другую ветку, например